# ListView get selected item text

Tags: android, listview, text, textview

I have this code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, 
                       int position, long id) {

    TextView txt = (TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.item_topic_name);

    // text is always null
}
```

item_topic_name is the textview id of the listview item, but the findviewbyId always returns null and the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get seleteditem text,use

```
((TextView) viewClicked).getText();
```

instead of

```
TextView txt = (TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.item_topic_name);
```

Because `viewClicked` is already a `view`,so simply cast it into  `TextView` and use  `getText()` to get selected item's text.

Comment: @MarioM Happy to help,don't forgot to accept and upvote it,so it may help others having similar issue.

Comment: only after 10 minutes I am allowed to select an answer.